# Issue while launching HIVE shell

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am unable to launch Apache Hive(0.14) ,I am getting following error

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient"

I have copied contents of hive-default.xml.template to hive-site.xml ,but modified following fields

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby://child1:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

I did not modified other fields in the hive-site.xml , Please can any one suggest me on how to resolve this issue.

BR,
sanumala

Comment: Can you check if you can start the local derby datawhere where your hiveserver is running? If it is fine, can you check if port 1527 is open?

Answer (score 0):

install this file 
slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar

cause if u have received this error, u need to install the above file
below is the error for not been able to launch hive shell;

---

[root@nn-1 hive]# hive
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.